# Use Base class type or Derived class type in for each loop

Tags: java, casting

Suppose I have this code:

```
class ABC 
{
   List<Orange> list;
   Orange orange;

   public static Fruit getFirstOrange()
   {
      list = getFruits();
      for(Fruit fruit:list)    // Here is the confusion
      {
        if(fruit.name.equals("orange")
        orange = (Orange) fruit;
        break;
      }
   }

   public List<Orange> getFruits()
   {
      return new List<orange>();
   }
}
```

So in the above code in the for each loop, should I use the type Fruit or Orange in this case.

```
      for(Fruit fruit:list)    // Here is the confusion
      {
        if(fruit.name.equals("orange")
        orange = (Orange) fruit;
        break;
      }

     *OR*

      for(Orange fruit:list)    // Here is the confusion
      {
        if(fruit.name.equals("orange")
        orange = fruit;
        break;
      }
```

So which one of the above is the correct way of doing it. I think since my list conatins orange, I should not use Fruit type in the for each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
List<Orange> fruit;
```

Then `for (Orange orange : fruit)` will loop over every fruit which *is an orange* because the fruit list can only contain Oranges. This is *the* best way to iterate the list because it applies *the* most-specific type which unifies the items.

Now, consider when a supertype is used

```
for (Fruit someFruit : fruit)   // an Orange is also a Fruit, okay
   someFruit.separateSlices();  // whoops! not all Fruit have slices
}
```

or

```
for (Object anyObject : fruit)  // an Orange is also an Object, okay
   anyObject.eat();             // whoops! can't eat random Objects
}
```

While a cast *could* be used, as all the items are guaranteed to be Oranges, it adds nothing to simply refining the type in the enhanced for-loop itself. Furthermore, using the specific type in the for loop *prevents* some trivial type-related mistakes. Consider this,

```
List<Fruit> fruit;            // now really fruit
for (Orange orange: fruit) {  // error: incompatible types, won't compile
                              // as not all Fruit are Oranges
   // ..
}
```

But with the cast,

```
List<Fruit> fruit = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
fruit.add(new Orange());
fruit.add(new Apple());               // valid, an Apple is also a Fruit
for (Fruit someFruit: fruit) {        // still most specific: Fruit, not Object
   Orange orange = (Orange)someFruit; // runtime ClassCastException on Apple
}
```

Thus, my suggestion is to *use the most specific/refined type* that applies to the problem domain. In the case of the original question that is to type each item as an Orange from the start; or perhaps to revise the assumption of using `List<Orange>` to store an assortment of different fruit.

Answer (score 1):

If `list` is a `List<Orange>`, then you should use `for (Orange o : list)` of course, as it is the type of the elements of the list.

---

If `list` is a `List<Fruit>` then you should use `for (Fruit f : list)`. The reason for this is that the list is able to hold elements of other types, such as `Apple` or `Banana` (provided you implemented them). Thus you should use the closest super class, which is `Fruit`.

Comment: I think it's not correct because of `List<Orange> list` (that a list of `Orange`s)?

Answer (score 1):

If your list is of type Orange, then you should use Orange. Your definition is

```
List<Orange> list;
```

So your loop can be

```
for(Orange o : list) {}
```

If your list was of type Fruit, then you would use Fruit in the loop, and cast as appropriate and necessary.